# Gaussian Process with scikitlearn - 95% confidence interval

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, forecasting

I have two arrays : X (382 samples x 37 features) and Y (382 samples x 8 values). I fit a `sklearn` gaussian process on it.

```
from sklearn import gaussian_process
gp = gaussian_process.GaussianProcess()
gp.fit(X_part1, Y_part1)
```

In a second time, I want to predict Y values related to other X values. I'm particulary interested in the 95% confidence interval, in order to have a plot like [in this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gp_regression.html).

```
y_pred, sigma2_pred = gp.predict(X_part2, eval_MSE=True)
sigma = np.sqrt(sigma2_pred)

print X_part2.shape
print y_pred.shape
print sigma.shape
```

> (382, 37)
>   (382, 8)
>   (382,)

But the fact is that the MSE (and therefore the sigma) is a 1-D array and I don't understand why. As soon as my Y is a 2d-array, I thought the MSE would be the same, as written in the documentation :

> An array with shape (n_eval, ) or (n_eval, n_targets) as with y, with the Mean Squared Error at x.

And as a result, I don't know how to deal with this MSE to get the filled 95% confidence interval...

Comment: Note that you are probably using the old version of the Gaussian process module. It has undergone a major change recently. Consider upgrading scikit-learn to the latest version.

Comment: What do you mean by "recently" ? I do have the official latest release (0.17, correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I mean the development version (future 0.18)

Comment: @eickenberg In fact, it is still not implemented. The [doc for dev version](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.predict) explains that the `y_std` is one-dimensionnal.   And there is no example for GPR with multiple outputs.

Comment: That is true. No multioutput yet. My bad.